# Unable to access and update custom attributes in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, custom-attributes, directoryentry

I'm hoping to make a breakthrough regarding updating Active Directory custom attributes using .NET (C#) using the normal `DirectoryEntry`.

I have an ages-old AD integration that regularly updates numerous out-of-the-box attributes with no problem. Recently, the AD team added two new custom attributes (a nullable boolean type, and a datetime type) to the AD user record which need to be updated with appropriate values. These attributes have no initial value and are "not set" when looking at them with MS AD Admin Center. I can manually modify the new attributes using that tool without issue.

In the solution, we do a `DirectorySearcher` call to get the desired `SearchResult`, loading the desired properties. Everything is there, including the custom attributes with their current values.

Next, we grab the `DirectoryEntry` with `SearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry()`. From here, I can update all the normal attributes, but while I can **see** the new custom attributes in the `DirectoryEntry.Properties.PropertyNames` collection, I cannot access them in any way to read their values or perform the required updates.

If I add a watch to the `DirectoryEntry.Properties.Values` collection, it errors out with:

> Unknown error (0x8000500c)

It's like they don't exist.

When I try to get the value, I get the error:

> 'entryToChange.Properties["TheCustomAttributeName"]' threw an exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException'

However, as I mentioned, if I access something like

```
entryToChange.Properties["SamAccountName"][0]
```

I see the value as expected and can update it without issue.

Next, I went into Powershell and **was** able to use `set-AdUser` to update one of the new custom attributes without any issue at all. My brain exploded... eyes rolled back... etc.

What am I missing with regard to updating new custom attributes in AD using .NET and the typical `DirectoryEntry` class? Thanks in advance for any insight.

Here's a simplified snippet of the code:

```
using (DirectorySearcher directorySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry, adQueryFilter, adAttributesToLoad)))
{
    SearchResult searchResult = directorySearcher.FindOne();
                        
    if (searchResult != null)
    {                            
        using (DirectoryEntry entryToChange = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry())
        {
            // BOOM! The error throws right here, when I try to look at the custom attribute
            if (entryToChange.Properties["TheCustomAttribute"] != null && 
                entryToChange.Properties["TheCustomAttribute"].Count > 0)
            {
                // We never get down here to do the update...
                entryToChange.Properties["TheCustomAttribute"][0] = "The new value";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it doesn't like the use of `.Any()`. I can't even get it to compile with `.Any()` (even if I have `using System.Linq`).

You can use `.Contains()` to check if the attribute has a value. If it doesn't have a value, then it will return `false`.

You can also use `.Value` to set the value if it's a single-value attribute.

```
if (entryToChange.Properties.Contains("TheCustomAttribute"))
{
    entryToChange.Properties["TheCustomAttribute"].Value = "The new value";
}
```

If there is still an exception, look at the properties of the `COMException` to see if there's an error code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The "Any()" was my mistake when typing out the sample code. The error "Unknown error (0x8000500c)" occurs when we simply try to access the named property using "entryToChange.Properties["TheCustomAttribute"]".

For example:
var foo = entryToChange.Properties["TheCustomAttribute"] throws the above error, but... var foo2 = entryToChange.Properties["SamAccountName"] works just fine.

The COMException contains the above error with no InnerException.

Comment: @AlexA I'm facing the same issue. Did you solve it?

Comment: @Elyasaf755, I decided to go with .NET Powershell libraries and building dynamic command variables to perform to updates. Works fine. Never did find a good way to use Directory Entry on custom attributes.